# What is the maximum of a function over the empty set?

Tags: analysis

could you answer my question?

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a subset of the real numbers and $f$ a continuous functions. What happens the function $\sup_{t \in A} |f(t)|$ if $A$ is chosen to be the empty set?

I feel like it is undefined but can anyone confirm? Thank you!

Comment: I think the supremum of the empty set is sometimes taken to be $-\infty$ so that you get $\sup( A \cup B) = \max( \sup(A), \sup(B))$

Comment: One common definition is $\sup\emptyset=-\infty$. A maximum obviously doesn't exist or make sense.

Comment: @Onir The same holds for other rules, such as $\sup(A\cap B) =\min\{\sup A,\sup B\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a *non-empty* subset $M \subset \mathbb R$. If $M$ is bounded above, then its supremum $\sup M$ is defined as the least upper bound of $M$. This is the unique number $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ with the following two properties:

1. $\alpha$ is an upper bound for $M$.
2. No $\beta < \alpha$ is an upper bound for $M$.

If $M  \subset \mathbb R$ is unbounded above (which automatically implies that $M \ne \emptyset$), then one defines $\sup M = +\infty$.

$\sup \emptyset$ has not yet been defined. What would be *adequate* in this case?

Clearly each $\beta \in \mathbb R$ is an upper bound for $\emptyset$, simply because $x \le \beta$ for all $x \in \emptyset$. In other words,the set of upper bounds of $\emptyset$ is $\mathbb R$. This set does not have a least element and therefore one defines
$$\sup \emptyset = -\infty .$$
Note that no $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ has the above properties 1. and 2.